# In CRM Dynamics 2013 how can I retrieve a list of accounts and create phone call activities against them for specific users

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a scenario where I need to get a list of accounts from CRM and then create phone-call activities against those accounts, also assign/splitting them amongst four different users, please see my code so far and please guide me to a solution for this scenario.

```
public static void CreatePhoneCallActivitesForRelatedAccount(IOrganizationService service)
    {
        QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
        qe.EntityName = "account";
        qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_accountactionedstatus");
        qe.Criteria.AddCondition("new_deliverystatus", ConditionOperator.Equal, 279640000);
        qe.Criteria.AddCondition("new_province", ConditionOperator.Equal, 100000018);
        qe.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0);
        //qe.Criteria.AddCondition("ownerid", ConditionOperator.In, "6DEFA813-56F9-E411-80CC-00155D0B0C2D", "CBDD653B-57F9-E411-80CC-00155D0B0C2D", "6CE879FD-56F9-E411-80CC-00155D0B0C2D");

        EntityCollection response = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe);

        foreach (Entity account in response.Entities)
        {
            PhoneCall phonecall = new PhoneCall
            {
                // ToDo: How can I add a phone call activity and assign it to the above created Accounts, also to splitting them amongst 4 users in the system
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
Guid[] users = new Guid[] { <id1>, <id2>, <id3>, <id4>};

var counter = 0;

        foreach (Entity account in response.Entities)
        {
            PhoneCall phone = new PhoneCall();

            ActivityParty _from = new ActivityParty();
            phone.OwnerId =
            _from.PartyId = new EntityReference("systemuser", users[counter % 4]);

            ActivityParty _to = new ActivityParty();
            _to.PartyId = account.ToEntityReference();

            phone.From = new ActivityParty[] { _from };
            phone.DirectionCode = true;
            phone.Subject = "phone call trial";
            phone.To = new ActivityParty[] { _to };
            service.Create(phone);

            counter++;  
        }
```

Just curious - have you tried to search an answer using search engine? I found an answer on the first page - https://www.google.com.ua/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=7I1hVvX4PI2u8we4v6iQAw#q=Microsoft+CRM+2011+Create+PhoneCall+C%23

Comment: I thought SO was the source of all knowledge on the internet?  ;)

Comment: @Daryl that's very true but I see no explanation why not to check Search Engine before you will ask question that was asked 100 times already. Do you see any or I have powerfull "Search Engine Usage" skills that are not available for others?

Comment: Totally agree.  I was just a attempting to be funny

Comment: @Daryl lol. I'm Ukrainian so we have issues with sense of humor :)

Comment: @Andrii Apologies for that, I am still new to CRM development and I couldnt find the right way to search for this particular issue, but I will keep that in  mind going forward.